# HTTPS ssl certificate WebView and CSS

Tags: css, ssl, https, webview, certificate

A few days ago I was trying to load an http url into an WebView and it worked fine. Now, I was doing the same thing but the html page is https with a self signed certificate.
The problem is that in https I can't load the CSS! Does anyone with a similar problem can help me with this issue?
Thanks...

Comment: I've seen this before, just trying to remember how we solved it. I know that if you visit the URL of the CSS file it'll ask you if you are sure you want to view the content. After saying yes, your CSS will start working for you on your own machine. If I remember the solution I'll be sure to post.

Comment: hey Jamie... I hope you remember the solution. I do really need this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually allow the certificate. The most simple way to allow it is to go in your source code, copy the css address, paste it in your address bar and a window should pop-up asking you to confirm the certificate (tested in firefox and chrome).

Otherwise in FF4/5 go to options/advanced/view certificates and click "add exception" and input the url location and than click on add certificate.

Comment: That's what I suspect... When making debug I get an SSL error [primary error: 2](http://ncc.dlut.edu.cn/course/android/source/docs/reference/android/net/http/SslError.html#SSL_IDMISMATCH) Do you know how to break this error?

Comment: @yugidroid Uh I can hardly help you from here on - my knowledge on certificates is quite basic - check what URL are you typing in (try a complete URL with www or check if you are typing in http or https).

Comment: Thanks easwee... I've found  way to accept manually the certificate and it worked. With the [onReceivedSslError(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedSslError(android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.SslErrorHandler, android.net.http.SslError)) method it is possible to accept that certificate using the handler. I used the _handler.proceed()_ and the problem is solved. Thanks again by the tip ;)